# Ryzen 4000 series processors clocking lower speeds on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

I have a Ryzen 7 4800H CPU which is clocked in at 2.9 GHz low and 4.2 GHz high. The clock speeds show the same on Windows and seem to run at the mentioned speeds.

However, the clock speeds show a considerably low speed on ubuntu. To be precise, here is what I am getting on running the following command:

`lscpu | grep MHz`

CPU MHz:                         1545.155

CPU max MHz:                     2900.0000

CPU min MHz:                     1400.0000

Is this an issue with others using 4000 series chips and is there an issue?
Please do suggest workarounds if available.